# How to take a screenshot with java from directX

Tags: java, directx, screenshot

I'm looking for a way to take a screenshot with a Java application of any running directX game. I use the following code

```
Robot robot = new Robot();  
GraphicsConfiguration config = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice().getDefaultConfiguration();  
BufferedImage screenshot = robot.createScreenCapture(config.getBounds());  
ImageIO.write(screenshot,"png", file);
```

This one works perfectly anywhere but in directX games. I'm not that familiar with Java and even less with DirectX, I'm just trying to adjust this code. I googled very much, but everything just leads to the same code I already have.

Do you know of another way to take a screenshot of DirectX games?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try doing this:-

```
try {  
                Robot bot = new Robot();  
                bot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_F6);  
                bot.delay(50);  
                bot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_F6);  
            } catch (AWTException ex) {  
                Logger.getLogger(main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);  
            }
```

Comment: What is this supposed to do? What is the purpose of the `F6` button?